# Should every post request include csrf token?

Tags: web-application, csrf

What is the vulnerability level if the anti-csrf token is not sent with every post request? (If the vulnerability levels were high, medium and low). I understand for critical functions like login etc you would need to include csrf token.

What factors should I consider when deciding whether or not to implement CSRF for each set of permitted requests in a web app?

Update: I found this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150203191328/https://www.checkmarx.com/2014/11/06/samsung-csrf-vulnerability/) here that explains need for csrf token for each request
It is interesting that more and more web apps are considering it for each request.

Comment: What is the _disadvantage_ of requiring the token for each request?

Answer (score 7):

If the POST changes state on the server then not including a csrf token leaves you vulnerable. The level of risk depends upon the specific functionality served at that URL if the attacker abuses it with a csrf attack.

Answer (score 2):

CSRF token should be part of a layered approach. You may [employ other techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) or other checks on session (CAPTCHA, require logon, out of band confirmation, etc.).

The cost to include a CSRF token is generally low, especially if you are working with a framework that can include it for you automatically. There are few cases where you will run into user compatibility issues (especially in normal human using a browser cases) You may want to think about cases where you *explicitly do not want to use CSRF*.

For example, cases where perhaps you want requests to be initiated directly. e.g., if you offer a search box on your site and require a CSRF token, it may make it impossible to create a quick search in the user's browser url bar.